# How to build Array of Lists of Structs in C# (with predefined size of the Array)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, oop, struct

Trying to build Array of Lists of Structs in C#. And getting a **System.NullReferenceException** with the best try (error on line `test[i].Add(info1);`)

*The question is not how to avoid **System.NullReferenceException** at all, but more like how to quickly build Array of Lists with predefined size of array, thus that one is able to use `array[i].Add(Struct)` in it. If possible without looping all over the array, just to create the lists.*

So these are the requirements:

- the size of the array should be predefined;
- the numbers of the lists per node should be arbitrary, and there should be a possibility that these are added easily;
- the structure should contain the `struct Info`.

This is the code, I have managed so far (copy and paste should work, to replicate the error):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Startup
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int entry = 1233;
        List<Info>[] test = new List<Info>[entry];

        for (int i = 0; i < 500 ; i+=3)
        {
            Info info1 = new Info()
            {
                capacity = i * 2,
                name = i.ToString()
            };
            test[i].Add(info1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i+=5)
        {
            Info info2 = new Info();
            info2.capacity = i * 2;
            info2.name = i.ToString() + i.ToString();
            test[i].Add(info2);
        }
    }

    struct Info
    {
        public int capacity;
        public string name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've only initialized the whole array not the Lists within.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb - is there some faster way than adding         `for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++) { test[i] = new List<Info>();}` before the loops?

Comment: test[i] = new List<Info> {info1};

Comment: @Vityata, please take a look at the edits in my answer.  Every multiple of 3 has 1 list, every multiple of 5 has 1 list, and every multiple of 3 and 5 has 2 lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of a the array are not defined as the object is a `List`

This is how you should do it :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Startup
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int entry = 1233;
        List<Info>[] test = new List<Info>[entry];

        for (int i = 0; i < 500 ; i+=3)
        {
            Info info1 = new Info()
            {
                capacity = i * 2,
                name = i.ToString()
            };

            // if null initialise the list
            if(test[i] == null) test[i] = new List<Info>();

            test[i].Add(info1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i+=5)
        {
            Info info2 = new Info();
            info2.capacity = i * 2;
            info2.name = i.ToString() + i.ToString();

            // if null initialise the list
            if(test[i] == null) test[i] = new List<Info>(); 

            test[i].Add(info2);
        }
    }

    struct Info
    {
        public int capacity;
        public string name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just skip the if check entirely in the firstly loop. It's always going to be true.

Comment: @CodeStranger Yes, kept it there simply in case he moves things around. If it was me i would have simply went with `List<Info>[] test = Enumerable.Range(0,entry ).Select(o=>new List<Info>()).ToArray();` and call it a day

Comment: @Franck - Idk, that 1 liner seems to have a lot of "sugar". In general I guess it is like a standard loop in performance. And I am "competing" with guys, who use C++ and "fancy" vectors, that do general magic when it comes to speed. (But the 1 liner is good, though)

Comment: @Vityata the one liner all it does is initialize all element of the array. You will not have a single null. If you would be to iterate on all elements and eventually have 100% of the array initialized then that one line will be faster. Compiler seems to like when the same operation is ask many times in a row as opposed to when needed. Again this is better is you initialise all the items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Startup
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int entry = 1233;
        List<Info>[] test = new List<Info>[entry];

        for (int i = 0; i < 500 ; i+=3)
        {
            Info info1 = new Info()
            {
                capacity = i * 2,
                name = i.ToString()
            };
            test[i] = new List<Info> {info1};
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 5)
        {
            Info info2 = new Info();
            info2.capacity = i * 2;
            info2.name = i.ToString() + i.ToString();
            if (test[i] == null)
            {
                test[i] = new List<Info> { info2 };
            }
            else
            {
                test[i].Add(info2);
            }
        }
    }

    struct Info
    {
        public int capacity;
        public string name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This assigns a new List in loop 2 to positions that already had a List from loop 1. It's a decent one line approach the first time an index is hit, otherwise you're losing info (in position 15 for example, like @Vityata mentions).

Comment: Adding a check before every time is a bit too much of a "patch", I would probably live with the 1-liner `for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++) { test[i] = new List<Info>();}`

Comment: @Vityata You could do that, but adding a null check is far less expensive than allocating the memory for all of the lists (for numbers not divisible by 3 and 5). However, if you were planning to use those lists later anyhow, then it seems the more sensible approach.

Comment: @ui_guy - null check is quick, yes, but the "price" of forgetting one seems to be quite high. I was hoping to have something "dynamic", "quick" and "clean". But the one thing I compromise here is the "quick" one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Startup
{
  static void Main()
  {
    int entry = 1233;
    var test = Enumerable.Range(0,entry)
      .Select(i=> {
        var y = new List<Info>();
        if(i%3==0 && i < 500)
        {
          y.Add(new Info {
            capacity = i*2,
            name = i.ToString()
          });
        }
        if(i%5==0 && i < 1000)
        {
          y.Add(new Info {
            capacity = i*2,
            name = i.ToString() + i.ToString()
          });
        }
        return y;
      }).ToArray();
    }

    struct Info
    {
        public int capacity;
        public string name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, in the general case it is faster (as far as it skips the meaningless loops). The idea of the two loops was to show, that data has to be able to be entered independently, thus that part of the code should stay as it is (e.g., 2 separate loops).

Comment: In that case, then I would just initialize all the elements with `var test = Enumerable.Range(0,entry).Select(i=>new List<Info>()).ToArray();`

Comment: This seems to be quite a good option so far. @Franck proposed the same in his/her comment.

Comment: The nice thing about the code I posted above is that can be easily transformed into being lazy.  Just remove the `.ToArray()`, and reference it as being an `IEnumerable<List<Info>>` instead, and it get calculcated as your consume it.  If you don't consume the whole thing, then you don't need to calculcate the entire array.

Comment: Well if performance is absolutely top priority, then I would suggest creating it the old fashioned way... `var test = List<Info>[entry]; for(var i=0;i<entry;i++) test[i]=new List<Info>();` instead.  The performance difference should be pretty minimal though.

Comment: Well, I am a bit afk now, but the LINQ is in slow in general, thus the difference should be visible, when 10^6 entries are given as an input or so. Will see tomorrow.

Comment: On my machine, the LINQ version runs in about .0000522 seconds. The optimized one I gave above runs in about .0000198 seconds. I rarely worry about that kind of difference, but it can matter if it's in a tight loop.  If you are initializing much larger numbers, then start to considering threading even... `var test = new List<Info>[entry];
  Parallel.For(0, entry,i=>{
   test[i]=new List<Info>();
  });` start to look good around 8000 entries I believe.. depending on hardware, and there are much better ways than that.